# PHP Class Function Calling

Tags: php, class, function, fatal-error

I'm writing my own php class and I have several functions within that class. But am I not allowed to call a function from another function within the same class? Something like this:

```
class my_Class {
    function one($arg) {
        //does something
    }

    function two($var) {
        $receive = one($var);
    }
}
```

I tried something like this and it spat out an error saying:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function one()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're coming from Java or C++, note that the use of `$this` in PHP (aka `self` in some other languages) is mandatory.

Comment: @Radu yah i'm fresh of the c++ boat :P thank you for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
function two($var) {
      $receive = $this->one($var);
 }
```

Review the PHP OOP reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php
The `$this` keyword is always required.

Comment: Yup, this is exactly what you need to change it too.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
class my_Class {
    function one($arg) {
        // does something
    }
    function two($var) {
        $receive = $this->one($var);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Radu .. i think you should do some test `one()` would not be global see  http://codepad.viper-7.com/Q85Tp4

Comment: @Radu ok valid argument it can also lead to `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare one()` .. i'll remove that option +1